# onblur will not work but onchange does work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

am i missing something? my onblur script does not work, but it works if i set it as onchange, i only have these two scripts running to run some validation on a few HTML inputs

the purpose of script #1 is to check that there is a space, indicating that the user has input a first and last name (there is probably a better way)

the purpose of script #2 is to check that the space is not blank when the user exits the input field

**Javascript**

```
  // Script #1
document.getElementById('name').onchange=function() {
  var theName = document.getElementById('name').value;

  if (theName.indexOf(' ') <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = "Must include first and last name";
  }
}


  // Script #2
document.getElementById('name').onBlur=function() {
  if (document.getElementById('name').value=="") {
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = "The name field is required";
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<label for="name" id="name_label">Name<span class="red">* </span></label><br>
<span id="name_error" class="hint"></span>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]" 
 placeholder="Full name please" maxlength="25" autofocus required>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a **typo** in your code, just replace `onBlur` by `onblur`.

```js
document.getElementById('name').onblur = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('name').value === '') {
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = 'The name field is required';
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="name" id="name_label">Name<span class="red">* </span></label><br>
<span id="name_error" class="hint"></span>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]" placeholder="Full name please" maxlength="25" autofocus required>
```

Also note that is a better practice use the `addEventListener` function **to handle events** in your DOM elements:

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  // your code...
});
```

Check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur) to get more information.

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code: Its `onblur`. Not `onBlur`.

```js
document.getElementById('name').onblur=function() {
  if (document.getElementById('name').value=="") {
    document.getElementById('name_error').innerHTML = "The name field is required";
  } else {
    // do something with this 'name'
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="name" id="name_label">Name<span class="red">* </span></label><br>
      <span id="name_error" class="hint"></span>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 ]" 
      placeholder="Full name please" maxlength="25" autofocus required>
```

Comment: You may need else condition I suppose!

Comment: @RayonDabre Good catch! I have edited my answer.

Comment: Downvote? Seriously??